# MYSQL: How can I store/retrieve a value based on the 3+ other values in the same table?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I'm making a program for an English class. I'd like to store data in this way:

```
ID      Object
0       Present Tense
1       1st person singular
2       To Be
3       I am
```

How can I retrieve the value for ID 3 based on IDs 0-2? The only thing I can think of is:

```
ID      Object     FromIDs
3       I am       0,1,2
```

The problem with this is that I'd have to do a fulltext index and I think this table is going to get pretty large. I don't want separate tables for different types of objects, if possible, because I don't know what I'll end up doing with these objects and I want as much flexibility as possible. I could have a second table relating IDs to each other, but I've only done that successfully relating a column from one table to a column to another.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't seem to get it - do you really want to store different kinds of data in the same field ('Object')?

Comment: They all interact with one another. For instance, instead of 1st person singular, I really want to have "I" which is just another word. This is a word table at it's simplest and the words will relate to each other in different ways. I'm trying to capture that complexity as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the data into different tables.  Have a table that stores the "tense" 
and another that stores the type "1st person singular".

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your problem a little more. From what you have I'm not sure if you're trying to go down the path of Entity-Attribute-Value or probably what is more likely is that relational database is not a good fit for your problem; you may need to use some sort of tree data structure. If you update, I can try to provide a better answer.

Comment: The basic problem is that in what I'm making there is no differentiation between an attribute and a value. Some values are just values and some attributes are just attributes, but most values are attributes and vice versa. For instance, "Present" is both a tense and a word that I might want to relate to in a different way. I'm trying to avoid data entry complexity by designing the database in a flexible and simple way.

Comment: Oh and I guess I am looking for a tree structure but with the ability to have leaves of one branch be the main branch elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What I've decided to do is a combination of what was suggested and what I originally thought. I'm going to have a master list with IDs that are auto-incremented and copied to other tables. That way, I have properties of different parts of speech separated, but still have everything relating to everything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a good fit for a relational database.  Sorry, you're trying to drive a nail using a screwdriver.

When you have no distinction between an attribute type and a value, you're modeling semantic data.  The open standard for this type of data modeling is [RDF](http://www.openrdf.org/).

Answer (score 0):

My solution (if you really dont want to break up the table)

```
**ParentChildTable**
ParentID ChildID 
0        3
1        3
2        3
```

But well, in one table now you have:
-type of tense
-type of person (1st, 3rd....)
-values
So i think it would be better to split, i can see .. .well, right now, 3 tables: values, tensetypes, personetypes and relationship table (value-value for tense/person)